# iCloud documents no longer in Mobile Documents folder?

Tags: ios, icloud

I have an app that creates a file in the iCloud documents folder. It is working fine, in that the devices that the app is installed on can access and update the file successfully. In my code, a NSLog of the file path gives me:

```
///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~my-company-name~appname/Documents/document_name
```

As part of my testing, I need to be able to view this file from my mac. Previously, I was able to do this by looking in my library/Mobile documents folder at the respective app folder.

However, I can't see the app folder in there. Any ideas why this would now not be showing up or pointers to configuration settings I could check? (I'm on Xcode 6.1, mac is Yosemite and all devices are iOS8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finder now treats this as a 'special' folder, so actively prevents you browsing the structure. You can do this if you use Terminal instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rob. I can still see other folders on the "Mobile Documents" folder using finder. I can see the same when I use the terminal. Has the location/path name changed?

Comment: I believe what Finder now shows you is what you can see in iCloud Drive - but this is only the public folder structure - there is still stuff that each app can sync over iCloud outside this - so ignore what you can see in Finder - if you want to see the full public structure you need to use Terminal. Unless you've changed the container used by your app the structure should still be `~/Library/Mobile Documents/your_container/Documents/document_name`.  If you're saving stuff in iCloud Drive also check `com~apple~CloudDocs` instead of your container.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I decided to migrate to iCloud drive, and I can now see all my files. I think I'd broken things with the previous file structure by some manual deleting and changing iCloud accounts etc. However, your answer and comments were very helpful.

Comment: Ah, this may have been your issue - iOS 8 gives the user the choice between Documents & Data or iCloud Drive, whereas Yosemite _will only work_ with iCloud Drive. So Yosemite won't have been showing any updates until you did so.

Comment: You're right. I only had the issue since upgrading to Yosemite. Thanks again.

Comment: The question is how do you get this folder to show in Finder??

Comment: You don't, it forces you to use Terminal. Apple don't want users looking in these folders so have coded Finder to make it as awkward as possible. I'm not aware of a way round this.